# extract value from json response using regular expression in c#

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013, jsonresult, web-performance

I am using visual studio 2013 to do web performance test for a web application, and I want to get a value from JSON response to use it in another request. Below is the JSON result \B

> ```
> "ResultMessage":
>    "Success","Result":{"IsAnonymous":false,
>              "DestinationBranchID":"5886c018-0a74-42c0-a334-f221beacdd49",
>              "ID":"83f65759-a442-4dbf-8772-550e5dec7933",
>              "No":943514207446,
>              "DestinationCityID":"43694b12-9c32-49d8-8e02-7663bbf7e07b",
>              "IssueDateTime":"2017-07-15T11:24:38",
>              "Amount":1500.0000,
>              "IsFeeIncluded":false,
>              "NetFee":200.0000,
>              "PayAtCashier":1700.0000,
>              "CustomerIdentityID":"f62c2def-04d8-46e6-a501-5c95423a4292",
>              "ReasonID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>              "BenefactorName":null,
>                "BenefactorPhone":null,
>                "BenefactorMobile":null,
>                "BeneficiaryName":"Test",
>                "BeneficiaryPhone":"09918367343",
>                "BeneficiaryMobile":"011686383",
>                "Note":"",
>                "RowVersion":"AAAAAAAAVp4="}}
> ```

I want to get the value of the ID field, I tried this regular expression \"ID\":\".*?"
but it gives me the whole "ID":"83f65759-a442-4dbf-8772-550e5dec7933", but i need only the Guid part

Comment: Have you tried with a capture group ? `\"ID\":\"(.*?)"` And get group 1 from the match? [Here you'll find an example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by building custom extraction rule to get value of a JSON column,

```
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool UseArrayResult { get; set; }

    public string ArrayName { get; set; }

    public override void Extract(object sender, ExtractionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Response.BodyString != null)
        {
            var json = e.Response.BodyString;
            var data = JObject.Parse(json);
            if (!UseArrayResult)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    e.WebTest.Context.Add(this.ContextParameterName, data.SelectToken(Name));
                    e.Success = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var result = data[ArrayName];
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        e.WebTest.Context.Add(this.ContextParameterName, result.SelectToken(Name));
                        e.Success = true;
                        return;
                    }
            }
        }
```

you have to send the UseArrayResult Param as true if the value you need inside the internal array and the ArrayName Param here as 'Result'. but if the value you need is existed directly then you have to send the UseArrayResult param as false